# High CPU usage by Clementine and Amarok

Tags: sound, 16.10

My high-end gaming PC with vanilla Ubuntu 16.10 has some issues with Amarok and Clementine. They are both using around 20 % of cpu time without any visualizations active etc. Amarok is currently using the VLC backend.

My CPU is i7-6700K@4GHz and my sound card is Cambridge Audio DacMagic+ in USB audio mode.

I mean this can't be right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change pulseaudio settings? My players eat a lot of CPU if I crank pulseaudio frequency or resampling algorithm too high.

Comment: No really. I tried to raise the `default-sample-rate` from 44100 to 48000, but that made the situation even worse.